# How to create a 4x4 array with hexadecimal input?

Tags: arrays, matlab, cryptography, hex, syntax-error

How can I create a 4x4 array with hexadecimal input in matlab?

I'm currently getting this error:

> Error using reshape
> To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change.

```
key =

  16×2 char array

    '41'
    '42'
    '43'
    '44'
    '45'
    '46'
    '47'
    '48'
    '49'
    '4A'
    '4B'
    '4C'
    '4D'
    '4E'
    '4F'
    '50'

w = (reshape (key, [4, 4]))';
```

Answer (score 2):

Hexadecimal numbers in MatLab are actually text string.

In your case, you do not have a (16 x 1) array, but a 16 x 2 string array.

You can have a 4 x 4 array of decimal data by converting the hexadecimal values using the [hex2dec](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hex2dec.html) function:

```
new_key=reshape(hex2dec(key),4,4)
```

Which gives:

```
new_key =

   65   69   73   77
   66   70   74   78
   67   71   75   79
   68   72   76   80
```

You can have a 4 x 4 string array of hexadecinal data by firdt converting the input array into a cell array:

```
c_key=cellstr(key)
c_key_1=reshape(c_key,4,4)
```

Which gives:

```
c_key_1 =
{
  [1,1] = 41
  [2,1] = 42
  [3,1] = 43
  [4,1] = 44
  [1,2] = 45
  [2,2] = 46
  [3,2] = 47
  [4,2] = 48
  [1,3] = 49
  [2,3] = 4A
  [3,3] = 4B
  [4,3] = 4C
  [1,4] = 4D
  [2,4] = 4E
  [3,4] = 4F
  [4,4] = 50
}
```

NOTE: Tested only with Octave

Comment: Just a small correction: OP's array is a (16 x 2) *char* array, not string array. I suspect the reshaping would have worked fine if it was a string array, as it would have been the correct size.